# How delete item from redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

i wonder how i can delete item with onClick from redux state.

```
let initialState = {
  items: [
      {
       name: 'A',
       age: 23
      },
      {
       name: 'B',
       age: 20
      },
      {
      name: 'C',
      age: 29
      }
     ]
    }
```

then i'm rendering my object with list in my component:

```
const listItems = this.props.MyState.items.map((item) =>
  <li key={item.name} onClick=event => this.props.deleteItem(event, item) >{item.name}</li>
);
```

and then passing this item to reducer with action.payload

but then i don't know how delete item from state.

eg: `action.payload` is item which i get at `onClick` how figure out this here?

```
case DELETE_ITEM:
      return { ...state, ? };
```

Comment: Filter out the item with that id should do the trick

Comment: If it doesn't have an id, you can always use the index :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Considering that your state is an `array of objects`, one solution would be to eliminate the selected item by their index. You should also avoid doing direct state-mutations, in redux as this will lead to side-effects. Always try to create a deep-clone or copy of the state if you plan on doing some sort of mutation (deletion, update). So to cover all the bases:

Your **reducer** should probably looks something like:

```
let initialState = {
  items: [
      {
       name: 'A',
       age: 23
      },
      {
       name: 'B',
       age: 20
      },
      {
      name: 'C',
      age: 29
      }
  ]
}

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
      case ADD_ITEM:
         ...
      case DELETE_ITEM:
         return {
           ...state,
           items: state.items.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
         }
   }
}
```

In this case, we're just going to setup the `action.payload` to just be the index of the item instead of entire item.

So your action creator should look like:

```
export const deleteItem = (index) => {
   dispatch({
      type: DELETE_ITEM,
      payload: index
   })
}
```

And now we can really simplify your mark-up. Simply use the `index` parameter in `.map()` as to satisfy the argument of our action-creator.:

```
const listItems = this.props.MyState.items.map((item, index) =>
  <li key={item.name} onClick={() => this.props.deleteItem(index)} >{item.name}</li>
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try replacing the state's array.

```
case DELETE_ITEM: {
 return {...state. items: state.items.splice(item.index, 1)};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

after spreading the current state, update the `items` by filtering it out of a unique property (eg: `id`):

```
case DELETE_ITEM:
      return { ...state, items: state.items.filter(i => i.id !== action.payload.id };
```